# highlighted lines in the achartengine grid

Tags: android, grid, achartengine

I try to create a custom grid for my ecg but nothing works.
I want to get a grid which has specific highlighted lines. To feaw the lines of the grid I use `xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setXLabels(10)` and `xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setYLabels(10)`.
And now I want to highlight every fourth line from the X and from the Y axis or make them just bigger than the other lines.
Here is something I found.

http://www.google.de/imgres?um=1&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&hl=de&biw=1680&bih=920&tbm=isch&tbnid=0PCpcj6UTWULcM:&imgrefurl=http://android.codeandmagic.org/2012/10/achartengine-live-scrolling-graph/2012-10-03-19-16-10-2/&docid=yfaTOinxMsdA-M&imgurl=http://android.codeandmagic.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2012-10-03-19.16.101.png&w=720&h=1280&ei=8bDCUdP3E8zPsgbKpICYBw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=317&page=1&tbnh=147&tbnw=83&start=0&ndsp=51&ved=1t:429,r:5,s:0,i:97&tx=29&ty=58

That is nearly what i'm looking for. But I also need the threahold for the y axis.
Has anybody an idea?
I'm happy about any hint!

Supplement:

Yes it was really easy to highlight the lines. I just add one Point at (0,20) and one at (1000,20). That works really fine for horizontal lines.

But if I want to do the same for vertical lines I get a diagonal line. For a static line chart it works, if I only add to points one at (30,0) and one at (30,100). But if I do the same for a real time line chart I only get this ugly slant. Can somebody explain it to me????
I also tried to change the values like (30,0) and (29,1000) but I still get the diagonal line :(

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add a few extra series that just contain 2 points each and each such series would define such a line.

Comment: oh yes, I thought there would be an easier way... but thank you for your answer, it is a good hint

Comment: ok now i tried it. but if I add two point the programm paint the second grid one point forward on the x axis. to I get a diagonal line like this \ and not a streight one like this |
What am I doing wrong. I don't tell you, that I draw a real time line chart with timeSeries. is that my problem?

Comment: It seems like the only thing in your chart is one series with the 2 points I mentioned. You need to have at least one more series with some points in it and the vertical line will start looking vertical.

Comment: Yes that it exectly what I'm doing. below you can see my code. What is the mistake? I am at my wit's end.

Comment: Hard to guess what the points you add to the Data series are at. Post a screenshot. Calm down.

Comment: ok I make a screenshop. the black line is the dynamic one. and the orange one should be the vertical line in the red box. I can not upload a picture because of that I upload it in dropbox. dropbox.com/s/vay16pfr0dlqxhx/screenshot.png

Comment: The line is almost vertical. The internal model doesn't support adding several points having the same X value, so this is why the second point is at 31 instead of 30. It's a known issue. However, I suggest you use XYSeries instead of TimeSeries.

Comment: hey dan. ah ok its a known issue... damned :P and you suggest to take XYSereies instead of TimeSeries. Would you be so kind and explain why?

Comment: You're not building a TimeChart, you are just building a LineChart. Try it and you'll see why I suggested that.

Comment: yes great. haha that was realy a very nice hint. thank you! it solved a lot of minor problems i had.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Thank you for ur answer. But i already have two series. I have one sereies that generate my dynamic graph. I try to show u my code.

```
public class TraceActivity extends Activity implements Observer
  {
  private GraphicalView view;
  private DynamicGraph dynamicGraph = new DynamicGraph();
  private static Thread thread;
  private dynamicValue value; //get from observable

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient);

     /* Thread for the graphs */
    thread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            { 

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                dynamicGraph.setRange();
                Point point = getDataFromReceiver(i, value);

        // here I try to add the vertical line 
            dynamicGraph.addNewLine(30, 0);    
          dynamicGraph.addNewLine(30, 100);    // this line is painted at 31,100)

                dynamicGraph.addNewPoint(point);

                View.repaint();

            }

        }
    };
    thread.start();

}

public Point getDataFromReceiver(int x, int parameter)
  {
    return new Point(x, parameter);
  }

@Override
  protected void onStart()
  {
    super.onStart();
    runOnUiThread(new ShowView(dynamicgraph.getView(this)));
  }

private class ShowView implements Runnable
   {
    GraphicalView graphView;
    public ShowTocoView(GraphicalView graphicalView)
    {
        graphView = graphicalView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (View == null)
        {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.View);
            View = graphView;
            layout.addView(View);
        }
        else
        {
            View.repaint();
        }
    }
}

public class DynamicGraph
{
    /** The chart view that displays the data. */
private GraphicalView view;

private TimeSeries Data = new TimeSeries("Toco");
private TimeSeries verticalLine = new TimeSeries("");

/** The main dataset that includes all the series that go into a chart. */
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

/** The main renderer that includes all the renderers customizing a chart. */
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

/** The most recently created renderer, customizing the current series. */
private XYSeriesRenderer rendererData = new XYSeriesRenderer();
private XYSeriesRenderer rendererVerticalLine = new XYSeriesRenderer();

GraphBuilder graphBuilder = new GraphBuilder(mRenderer, 10);

public TocoGraph()
{
    mDataset.addSeries(Data);
    mDataset.addSeries(verticalLine);

    // graphBuilder build the grid and set the XYSeriesRenderer
    graphBuilder.setAndAddXYSeriesRenderer(rendererData, Color.BLACK, 2f);
    graphBuilder.setAndAddXYSeriesRenderer(rendererVerticalLine,
            Color.rgb(247, 131, 62), 2f);

}

public GraphicalView getView(Context context)
{
    view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, mDataset, mRenderer);
    return view;
}

public void setRange()
{
    graphBuilder.setRange(Data, 100, 0);
}
public void addNewPoint(Point p)
{
    Data.add(p.getX(), p.getY());

}

public void addNewLine(int x, int y)
{
    verticalLine.add(x, y);
}   }
```

So there is no reason for me, why the vertical line is not vertical. Have you an idea?